# searching a playlist and playing a song

Tags: android, listview, search, playlist

I'm trying to implement search in the music player.

```
 public class PlayListActivity extends ListActivity {
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
public String songList[];

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager(getApplicationContext());
    // get all songs
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();
    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
    }

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transperent_color));
    lv.setDividerHeight(1);
    // listening to single listitem click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
    // getting listitem index
        int songIndex = position;

    // Starting new intent
   Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
    MusicPlayerActivity.class);
        // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
        in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
        setResult(100, in);
        // Closing PlayListView
        finish();
        }
    });

/**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            Log.v("LOG",cs.toString());
            ((Filterable) adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);  

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
        }
    });

}
}
```

I'm able to search the song.. but if I play that song, some other song plays (according to the position number)
how do I change it so it plays the specific song that i search for..

Thank you for your time and help! :)

Comment: It must be the position issues, I think when you search songs after that notify your listview again.

Comment: How do i do that? Please help me modify the code accordingly. Thanks a lot

Comment: Where you click actually in listview or on AutoCompleteTextView when search, can you please clarify?

Comment: Listview is where i click

Comment: Just thik, when you search after that set listview adapter again with your search results value. and make adapter.notifiDatasetChanged(); it will set your listview again.

Comment: have you did it or not still???

Comment: ok, can you send me your whole project code, so I can do it.

Comment: How do I send it to you?

Comment: on my mail id SANA....I will give you, when you come online just comment here, after tht I will give you ok

Comment: Hi, Pratik.. Pls pass me your mail id. I'll send the code. Thank you

Comment: Hi Pratik.. I've emailed. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: hey I have got yr issue for playlist, where are you nw a days?

Comment: hey are you done with this or nt?